# Does Eclipse shows what are the list of classes extending current class

Tags: eclipse

I am curious to know if eclipse has the feature of showing all the list of classes that are extending the current class. This feature is available in INTELLIJ..any ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **Type Hierarchy View**.

The type hierarchy tree shows supertypes, subtypes or both of a given type depending on the selection made in the toolbar.

"Show the Subtype Hierarchy": This command displays the subtypes of the selected class and/or all implementors of the interface in the Hierarchy view. The tree starts at the selected type and displays the result of traversing down the hierarchy

Answer (score 11):

Others have mentioned the *Type Hierarchy View*. There's also the *Quick Type Hierarchy*: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: Yes, Ctrl+T is a very useful shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

It's called Type Hierarchy. Default keyboard shortcut key is F4.

There's couple of ways to do this.

1) Open the code, click it's class declaration and press F4 or Right click and select "Open Type Hierarchy F4" menu option.

2) Right Click on the source File, and select "Open Type Hierarchy F4"

PS. For more Eclipse Shortcut key, press Ctrl+Shift+L or select "Help"->"Key Assist.... Ctrl+Shift+L" menu option.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [Type Hierarchy](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-6.htm)